# Unable to run Flask app on Azure App ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0

Tags: python, opencv, azure-web-app-service

I tried changing opencv-python to opencv-python-headless too but no effect on the error. I am linking GitHub to the deployment center.

Even tried adding libgthread-2.0 to the `requirements.txt` but of no use.

```
  File "/tmp/8d994faa0eee02e/app.py", line 3, in <module>
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.264279725Z     import os, sys, cv2, glob
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.264282925Z   File "/tmp/8d994faa0eee02e/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.264286525Z     from .cv2 import *
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.264289725Z ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.272103487Z [2021-10-22 01:34:07 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.401211514Z [2021-10-22 01:34:07 +0000] [36] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
  2021-10-22T01:34:07.402045221Z [2021-10-22 01:34:07 +0000] [36] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope You are using the **WebApp** for **containers**. If not please use the **WebApp containers** and bring your own container, it’s the same flow during creation but just that you have to choose **docker** or another **container registry**. Take a look [here](https://prashanthmadi.github.io/2017/07/03/playing-piano-python-app-in-azure-app-services-linux-new.html) this blog have a sample Flask app.

Refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e090de85-1827-4195-b05f-53c98118ed92/import-cv2-in-azure-webapp?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for same fix

Other possible way of fix follows:

use `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install install libgtk2.0-dev`.

Refer [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1328)

Comment: No, I am just relying on the installs from requirements.txt and uploading all the codes and files by linking through GitHub.

Comment: I simply followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask and it all went well and the easiest way in my opinion.